# Did my rsync successfully back-up all data or not?

Tags: rsync

It looks like not a single byte is missing after the rsync, but there were some errors:

```
ujjain@DS3018xs:/volume1$ cat rsync.sh
rsync -av photo.tar /var/services/homes/ujjain/nfs/RAIDF1/
rsync -av music.tar /var/services/homes/ujjain/nfs/RAIDF1/
ujjain@nas:/volume2/Files/RAIDF1$ ls -al
total 418910340
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 admin        users           36 Nov 29 22:54 .
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 ujjain users          410 Nov 29 21:47 ..
-rw-------  1 admin        users  53127639040 Nov 29 20:52 music.tar
-rw-------  1 admin        users 375836549120 Nov 29 20:50 photo.tar
ujjain@nas:/volume2/Files/RAIDF1$
root@DS3018xs:/volume1# ls -al *tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ujjain root  53127639040 Nov 29 20:52 music.tar
-rw-r--r-- 1 ujjain root 375836549120 Nov 29 20:50 photo.tar
root@DS3018xs:/volume1# cat nohup.out
sending incremental file list
created directory /var/services/homes/ujjain/nfs/RAIDF1
photo.tar
rsync: chown "/var/services/homes/ujjain/nfs/RAIDF1/.photo.tar.qeeaLI" failed: Operation not permitted (1)

sent 375882427699 bytes  received 31 bytes  107165339.34 bytes/sec
total size is 375836549120  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1355) [sender=3.0.9]
sending incremental file list
music.tar
rsync: chown "/var/services/homes/ujjain/nfs/RAIDF1/.music.tar.mHlkfL" failed: Operation not permitted (1)

sent 53134124438 bytes  received 31 bytes  105739551.18 bytes/sec
total size is 53127639040  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1355) [sender=3.0.9]
root@DS3018xs:/volume1#
```

Did my rsync succesfully back-up all data or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your files were backed up, but the file ownership was not.

Your destination appears to be some kind of file share, (NFS?) which doesn't permit you to change the ownership of the files you wrote to it.

It appears that the files you backed up are owned by a different user than the user which ran rsync, thus rsync attempts to change the ownership of the destination file to match. Because it can't do so, you receive this error.

You can resolve the problem by changing the file ownership of the source files.

Comment: You could also add the `--no-owner` option to the `rsync` commands, which tells them not to try to set the files' owner.